# MySQL group records based on a column value

Tags: mysql

Here's my table schema:

[image: Table Schema for Test Table]

In the above test table I want to group my records by **user_by** and **message_type** only when the **message_type = "push_message"**.

I am trying to achieve it without any sub query, suggestions please.

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM `test` group by (CASE WHEN message_type = 'push_message' THEN user_by ELSE id END);
```

But throws an error in MySQL.

Here's what I want:
[image]

Comment: if you group by your user_by and message_type then some of your matching field will be disappear. So do you really need to do this with losing those fields or not.

Comment: please make a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), so that we can help you rightly.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to make the query but it doesn't work? As @FrayneKonok suggested, you should provide an example.

Comment: What would the desired result look like? (Why do we still have to ask this?)

Comment: if you want to message_type = "push_message" then no need to group by message_type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. After some more research I got it right.

```
SELECT id,
       user_id,
       user_by,
       message_type
FROM test
GROUP BY IF(message_type = 'push_message', concat(user_by, message_type), id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple example of GROUP_CONCAT, You may get your desired output after run this/ execute this. The example is with a delimiter ', ' as well, so you can quick understand the things.

The GROUP_CONCAT function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values

```
SELECT id, user_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_by ORDER BY user_by DESC SEPARATOR ', ')  as user_by
    FROM test 
WHERE message_type = 'push_message'
GROUP BY user_by;
```

This may help you, if not then please let me know and make a fiddle to understand what actually happen!

If you need to keep other field then please do the GROUP_CONCAT for all these, otherwise the other data go away from the output table.

Comment: That doesn't help. I have edited the question to give you a clear picture of what I want. Tell me if you want anything else.